# What's the difference between DetailedHTMLProps and HTMLAttributes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a component interface that should extend the interface of a standard `<div>` element. What's the difference in writing this:

```js
interface ComponentProps extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement> { ... }
```

versus this:

```js
interface ComponentProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> { ... }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

lets create `ComponentProps` types:

```
interface ComponentProps1 extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement> {}

interface ComponentProps2 extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {}
```

then we can check the difference between them quite easily:

```
type Dif = Omit<ComponentProps1, keyof ComponentProps2>;
```

the `Dif` type is:

```
type Dif = {
    ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>;
    key?: string | number;
}
```

Comment: So `DetailedHTMLProps` only includes `key` and `ref`? Aren't those set on both class and functional components in React automatically? When will I ever need to extend `DetailedHTMLProps`?

Comment: `key` and `ref` are defined on react class and functional component but at the same time, they do not defined `HtmlAttributes`. It is reasonable to use this type for all `JSX.IntrinsicElements`. I think I would not extend `DetailedHTMLProps` as it should be used as a wrapper for your `HtmlAttributes<Element>`

Comment: @Marcin, thank you for the great answer. I have another question, what are the ref and key used for? is there a reason I would want to use DetailedHTMLProps instead of just HtmlAttributes ?