# Getting type of HTML element's attributes

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, dom

I would like to create a React component in Typescript that has all the same attributes as the HTML `<select>` element.

How would I type this?

```js
type Props = {
  label: string
} & HTMLSelectElementAttributes; // This one is wrong


function MySelect(props: Props) {

  return <label>{props.label}</label><select {...props}>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
  </select>;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a type-aware IDE like VSCode, if you hover over the `<select`, you'll see:

```
React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>
```

You can use that as the type for the other props.

```
type Props = {
    label: string;
} & React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>; // This one is wrong

const MySelect = (props: Props) => (
    <div>
        {' '}
        <label>
            label
            {props.label}
        </label>
        <select {...props} />
    </div>
);

// Example usage in which no type warnings result
const X = () => <MySelect label="foo" onChange={() => { console.log('change'); }} />;
```

Comment: Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418950/whats-the-difference-between-detailedhtmlprops-and-htmlattributes  It's probably better to just use `React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>`, but you sent me in the right direction, thanks!